# Indentation inside theorem environment

Tags: theorems, latex3, xparse

I'm trying to get a theorem-derived environment to indent the entire block of text.  What I have is

```
\theoremstyle{aside}  
\newtheorem{asides}{Aside}[chapter] 
\NewDocumentEnvironment{aside}{m o}
{\begin{adjustwidth}{1in}{0em}
\IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\asides \label{#1} \addtheocontentsline[]{#1}{Aside}}
    {\asides[#2] \label{#1} \addtheocontentsline[#2]{#1}{Aside}}
    \ignorespaces
\end{adjustwidth}
}
{\endasides}
```

where you type `\begin{aside}{label}[Title]` and it puts it into the TOC based on a discussion here: [AMS theorems in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60872/ams-theorems-in-table-of-contents)

The whole {aside} block should indent.  However, what's happening is that only the header indents and nothing else.  (When I try to adjust the indent in the {aside} environment style, the same thing happens}.

Comment: You have put `\end{adjustwidth}` in the begin code for the `aside` environment, ie. before the body starts. This means that in the body the normal indentation is restored, just as you observe. I think the `\end{adjustwidth}` must be put in the end code, i.e. just before `\endasides`. I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: If I swap the `}` with the `\endadjustwidth` (`}
\end{adjustwidth}
{\endasides}`), I end up with the error `Extra \endgroup. \end{adjustwidth`

Comment: That's not what I meant. `...\ignorespaces}
{\end{adjustwidth}\endasides}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're placing wrongly `\end{adjustwidth}`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% guess
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtheocontentsline}{omm}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
    #3 \protect\ref{#2}%
    \IfValueT{#1}{ (#1)}%
  }%
}


%\theoremstyle{aside} % no idea what this should be
\newtheorem{asides}{Aside}[chapter] 
\NewDocumentEnvironment{aside}{mo}
  {%
   \adjustwidth{1in}{0pt}
   \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\asides\addtheocontentsline{#1}{Aside}}
     {\asides[#2]\addtheocontentsline[#2]{#1}{Aside}}%
   \label{#1}%
  }
  {%
   \endasides
   \endadjustwidth
   \addvspace{\topsep}
  }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{aside}{foo}[Whatever]
\lipsum[3]
\end{aside}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

I had to guess a definition for `\addtheocontentsline`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one could do it very easily with the `ntheorem` package:

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremindent=1in

\newtheorem{asides}{Aside}[chapter]
```

The package defines a customisable `\listtheorems` command, analog of `\listoffigures`, except the heading has to be defined.

Comment: I actually want the `aside` entries to go in the main ToC rather than in a custom secondary list.